# Converter .docx para pdf em c# sem utilizar Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, pdf

Olá,

Estou com problemas para converter um documento em formato docx para pdf sem utilizar Microsoft.Office.Interop. Outras DLLs que encontrei não são free.

Alguém tem uma dica?